# keypress event - how to delete the key after the event occurred?

Tags: javascript

My goal: when the user clicks a key, I need to compare the key with the first letter of a string. if it matches, I need to write in the text-field that string.

by using keypress function, it works in this way:

1. enter the function that was invoked with keypress.

2.in the function it does:
document.getElementById("name").value="shiran";

1. then it adds the character the user pressed (which will be s)

and the result is "shirans" instead of just the string ("shiran").

I cannot use the functions keyup and keydown as they don't work with keycode.

the required results: the string in the text field.

the actual results: the string+ the key that was pressed in the text field.

here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>cookies</title>
</head>

<body>

<form >
user name: <input type = "text" id='name' onkeypress='completeFields(event);'> </br>

</form>

<script>

function completeFields(e){

//get the key
var unicode;
if (e.keyCode)
    unicode = e.keyCode;
else
    unicode = e.charCode;

var username="shiran";
var ch1=username.charAt(0);
var ch2 = String.fromCharCode(unicode);
if(username!=null && username!=""  && ch1==ch2)
{

    document.getElementById("name").value="shiran";
}
}

</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the question?  If this doesn't work, please describe how it differs from the desired behavior.

Comment: Not sure that link is going to the correct bin.

Comment: A note on your "I cannot use the functions keyup and keydown as they don't work with keycode": they most definitely do. If they don't in your code, then your code is wrong, rather than the event not using keyCode

Comment: It's funny that you said that.. cause if you are right then I could simply use the function keyup rather than keypress.. and then I won't have any problem at all..but I can't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/tWkEx/) what you're trying to do?

Relevant JavaScript:

```
(function (D, S, undefined) {
    'use strict';
    var base, field;
    field = D.getElementById('name');
    base = 'shiran';
    field.onkeypress = function (e) {
        var char;
        char = S.fromCharCode(e.keyCode);
        if (char !== base[0]) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    };
}(document, String));
```

And, embedded in a cleaned up version of the OP's code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf8" />
        <title>cookies</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form >
        <label>
        <span>user name: </span> 
            <input data-base="shiran"  id="name" onkeypress="autoComplete(event);" type="text">
        </label>
    </form>
    <script>
        (function (S, W, undefined) {
            'use strict';
            function autoComplete (e) {
                var base, char, input, value;
                input = e.currentTarget;
                base = input.dataset.base;
                value = input.value;
                char = S.fromCharCode(e.keyCode);
                // We'll handle the keyup if the char isn't just whitespace
                if (!/\s+/.test(char)) {
                   e.preventDefault();
                }
                if (char === base[value.length]){
                    input.value = base;
                }
            }
            W.autoComplete = autoComplete;
        }(String, window));
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry. I don't understand what you did.

Comment: I added a fiddle to try and make it clearer. Basically, I'm using ```e.preventDefault();``` to keep the event from propagating.

Comment: Could you please add it to my original code ? I am not sure how to do it.

Comment: @jameslafferty.. thank you very much for your effort.. however.. it doesn't do what I wanted at al.. all I wanted was simply to delete the last character that has been attached to the text field after the event keypress happend.. and keep the string it had in the text field..

Comment: Are you looking to replicate a kind of autocomplete? (It's pretty easy to adjust the code, just maybe not clear on what you're asking.)

Comment: so if you run my code.. and you press "s".. you will get "shiran"+"s" in the text field.. but I want only the string..only "shiran".. without the "s" in the text field.. did you get me?

Comment: Check out the edits I made... I think I got what you're after now.

Comment: It seems to work perfectly fine.. however I can't recreate it.. it's written in a way which I didn't learn.. how can you make it more like my original code? (with the function onkeypress in the html code)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43942/discussion-between-jameslafferty-and-shiran)

Answer (score 0):

Use `event.preventDefault` method or `return false` to prevent browser event - adding character in input.

Comment: return false wont work. and where shell I place the event.preventDefault?

Comment: `function completeFields(e){ e.preventDefault()` ... other code